# Redirect requests mapped to a DNS IP Address

Tags: dns, iptables, ip

For this command lines:

`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport port -j DNAT --to-destination ip:port

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

I can reroute to **ip:port**

But how do I use a DNS instead? For example:

**--to-destination mynetwork.dyndns.com:80**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **redirect DNS quries** you can try this.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ethX -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to $(get lan_ipaddr)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ethX -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to $(get lan_ipaddr)
iptables -t nat -L -v -n # shows nat table
```

and if you try to **forward port 80 to another ip**. Here is the rule and a example of it.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p ${PROTOCOL} -i ${INTERFACE} -d ${LOCAL_IP_ADDR} --dport ${LOCAL_PORT} -j DNAT --to ${DESTINATION_IP_ADDR}:{DESTINATION_PORT}
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.10 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.2:80
```

Please let me know in case of queries or if it was the answer of your question.